# Burkes theorem and M/M/1 queue

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Burke's theorem says that the output process of an $M/M/1$ queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$ follows a Poisson with parameter $\lambda$. Suppose after service completion the customer enters state 1 with probability $p$ and state 2 with probability $1-p$. Suppose that the current state is $(\text{number of customers in the queue},state\  1, state \ 2)=(N,n,m)$. I am interested in finding the rate of going from $(N,n,m)$ to $(N-1,n+1,m)$. Initially I thought the rate is $\mu p$. But I guess Burkes theorem says that the rate is $\lambda p$. Which one of the two is correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's $\mu p$, provided $N > 0$, because when the current state is $(N, \cdot, \cdot)$, the server ejects customers at rate $\mu$. The *overall* exit rate is $\lambda$, because there is a probability $1-\rho$ that the server is empty—i.e., the state is $(0, \cdot, \cdot)$—in which case the server ejects customers at rate $0$. If $N = 0$, then of course the only transition out of that state is an arrival.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a interpretation of the quantity $\lambda p$? Is it the overall rate at which customers go from the queue to state 1?

Comment: Yes. The exit stream from the server is Poisson at rate $\lambda$, so they enter bucket $1$ (best to avoid the word "state" there, I think) at rate $\lambda p$, still Poisson as long as the exit bucket is chosen i.i.d. Bernoulli.